# Haskell iterate argument types don't match, why?

Tags: loops, haskell

I have a function `appendLetters :: [[Char]] -> [[Char]]`. When I try to call this function in with `iterate` like this: `iterate appendLetters [""]`, ghci tells me:

```
Couldn't match type '[Char]' with 'Char'  
Expected type: [Char] -> [Char]  
  Actual type: [[Char]] -> [[Char]]  
In the first argument of 'iterate', namely 'appendLetters'  
In the second argument of 'genericTake', namely  
  '(iterate appendLetters [""])'  
In the expression: genericTake n (iterate appendLetters [""]) 

Couldn't match expected type 'Char' with actual type `[Char]'  
In the expression: ""  
In the second argument of 'iterate', namely '[""]'  
In the second argument of 'genericTake', namely  
  '(iterate appendLetters [""])'
```

Failed, modules loaded: none.

Why does `iterate` expect to have these argument types? How can I make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Full code:

```
wordsOfLength :: [Char] -> Integer -> [[Char]]  
wordsOfLength alphabet n = genericTake n ( iterate appendLetters [""] ) where appendLetters words = [ atFirst ++ [letter] | atFirst <- words , letter <- alphabet ]
```

Explanation: wordsOfLength should take an alphabet and create all words of length n over this alphabet. This is a homework assignment and I don't want to get help with solving the task itself, but only with the iterate function.

Comment: This typechecks for me.  `:t iterate (undefined :: [[Char]] -> [[Char]]) [""]` says the result is `[[[Char]]]`.

Comment: Could you post the full function where you use this expression? Even better, a runnable example.

Comment: Also, what is `appendLetters` supposed to do? It is not obvious from your chosen type where the letters should come from, or what they should be appended to.

Comment: I edited the original post so you can understand my problem better. Thank you for looking at my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression

```
iterate appendLetters [""]
```

has type `[[[Char]]]` (`iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]`, and in your case `a == [[Char]]`). So the result of `genericTake` will have the same type. But your `wordsOfLength` function has the output type `[[Char]]`, which causes the type mismatch.

Intuitively, you are returning a list (over lengths) of lists (of possible words), where words are lists themselves, so it's `[[[Char]]]`.

Comment: From a different point of view: your problem is not `iterate`, but `genericTake`. The latter picks the n first elements of the list, and thus results in a new list. You want something akin to `genericIndex` instead, which results in the element at index n. (Just be aware that `genericIndex` will crash your program if you give it a negative index.)

Comment: Your answers helped me a lot, thank you. Now everything works as intended.